# export commands ignored in /etc/apache2/envvars script -

Tags: 11.10, configuration, apache2, environment-variables

Maybe this belongs to Serverfault or launchpad.net, but here we go anyway:

In Oneiric, 
there is an `export` command in this script /etc/apache2/envvars , setting LANG. 
This gets ignored on my server. Any idea why?

I had  two more commands in Script /etc/apache2/envvars

```
export SYBASE=/opt/sybase  
export SYBASE_OCS=OCS-15_0
```

but they get ignored as well 
as the output from the [printenv.cgi](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/articles/pl020001.shtml) script shows.

**Is this a bug or a security feature in Oneiric?**

Note that the answer from Sep 27 2011 at 17:29 to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable) *explicitly says* that admins should add `export` commands to /etc/apache2/envvars .

I found this:
A quote from the Oneiric [changelog](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.ubuntu.devel.changes.oneiric/4319) regarding Package sbox-dtc

```
- Removed the use of Apache envvars which aren't safe (easy to hack).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PassEnv SYBASE SYBASE_OCS` in your apache config file.

Also you may have to stop/start apache (restart was not working for me)

See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/340335/creating-new-variables-in-etc-apache2-envvars/3) on serverfault